# Finding birth family of Betsey Richmond who married in mid 19th century Liverpool?

Tags: 19th-century, england, birth-records, lancashire

I have hit a complete brick wall concerning my three times great grandfather and his family.

John Jenkinson (appears as Jinkinson on marriage certificate) married Betsey Richmond on 14th August 1837 at St Nicholas Church, Liverpool.
Both are shown as "Minors" and resided at Oxford Street North, Liverpool.

- John's occupation is shown as "Mariner", but his father's name and profession are shown as "Robert Hodkinson, Soldier"
- Betsey's father's details are given as "Robert Richmond, Mariner".

I have been unable to find any information on any of those named prior to the wedding details, and nothing whatsoever on John Jenkinson in any of the following census data sets.

John and Betsy (different spelling!) had a son, Robert Richmond Jenkinson, born on 20th May 1839 whilst they resided at Marys Place, Chadwick Street, Liverpool.
I can find no further records of any other children being born to John and his wife Betsy.

Robert Richmond Jenkinson died on 25th August 1871 in East Haddon, Northants, having married Martha Hadley in East Haddon on 26th June of the same year. Martha had previously given birth to a son (Francis Richmond William) on 7th October 1870, but the fathers name was omitted from the birth certificate. The forename "Richmond" seems to be a strong clue towards the father's identity!!
Robert Richmond Jenkinson's death certificate states his occupation as "Army Pensioner, late Private 4th Foot", so perhaps he followed in the footsteps of his grandfather Robert Hodkinson? His occupation shown on his marriage certificate shows him to be a "Moulder", and his father is shown as "John Jenkinson, Sailor".

I am intrigued with the army and nautical connections of my Jenkinson (Jinkinson) and Richmond family roots.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  I see you've taken the tour, but I would also encourage you to read the material in the [help], starting with [What topics can I ask about here?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).  General "I need any information" questions can be broad, and don't always yield good answers.  You can edit your question at any time by using the [edit] link underneath. It's okay to write multiple questions about the same family.

Comment: You have a couple of generations listed here.  Leave your account of your research in place so we can see what you've done, but think about picking out one individual and deciding on a focused research question about their life. That will be more likely to yield good answers. Also, don't be alarmed if your question gets edited, since large blocks of text with no paragraph breaks are difficult to read.

Comment: I think there are at least two distinct questions that you could ask, and these should be asked as separate questions.  Those questions are "Identifying birth family of John Jenkinson?" and "Identifying birth family of Betsey Richmond?"  I think you should use the [edit] button beneath this question to revise it to one or other, and then ask the other question as a [new question](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).  Don't worry if it feels clumsy to do this, there are plenty of veteran users of this site who can help you frame more focussed questions (and these get answers!)

Answer (score 2):

Robert Richmond (mariner) married Alice Bradshaw on 4th August 1817 at Lancaster, St Mary. Both are recorded as being of this town and parish.

There's a christening for Betsey Richmond in 1819 in the same parish listing her parents as Robert and Alice. And also a baptism at Overton for on the 21st February 1819, which is probably where they actually lived.

Significantly, there's a baptism for John Jenkinson on 9th March 1817 at Overton that only mentions a mother, Betty Jenkinson.

Comment: HI, Stewart -- welcome to G&FH.SE!  Did you mean to create a new account to use only on this site?  Could you also add some information about your sources and source-of-source for the information in your answer? (e.g. where did you see the parish registers?)

Comment: https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:NXG3-4PD

Comment: https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:NXY5-Q2H

Comment: https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:NXNY-HRM

Comment: https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:NXH4-C3P

Comment: https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:J9L6-781

Comment: The marriage record for Robert Richmond and Alice Bradshaw is viewable at Ancestry.co.uk

Comment: Did not mean to set up additional account. Can I fix?